# CocoaPods: How can I wrap a pure swift static library precompiled binary into a pod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've the following files, that have been precompiled, for some library, let's call it `Foo`

```
Foo.swiftmodule/
     *.swiftmodule, swiftinterface, etc
iphoneos/
    libFoo.a
iphonesimulator/
    libFoo.a
```

This is a bit awkward, because since the advent of apple silicon, you can't just combine x86_64 and arm64 into a single fat binary `libFoo.a`; you need a simulator-specific arm64 as well as a real-device arm64, hence the two directories.

I can link these directly into my application's xcode project by specifying this stuff:

```
"LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "/path/to/foo/iphoneos",
"LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = "/path/to/foo/iphonesimulator",
"SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS" = "/path/to/foo",
```

However, referencing this binary static library from CocoaPods is proving difficult.

What I'd like to do, is wrap these up in a `podfile`, so that other people can reference my pod, and have the swiftmodule and `.a` files linked automatically.

95% of what I've found thus far about CocoaPods is centered on distributing source code only (which I can't do), and the 5% remaining that talks about binaries is all assuming objective-C frameworks with header files. This is pure swift, I have no header files.

---

Attempt #1

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    # name, version, etc elided  
    s.source_files = ['Foo.swiftmodule', 'iphoneos/libFoo.a', 'iphonesimulator/libFoo.a']
    s.preserve_paths = '*'
  
    s.xcconfig = { 
      "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos*]" => "iphoneos",
      "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" => "iphonesimulator",
      "SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS" => ".",
    }
end
```

sadly results in

```
The Swift pod `my-other-pod` depends upon `Foo`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

Comment: Have you tried using `s.vendored_library = libFoo.a`? Also `libFoo` should be a fat binary. If swift probably static framework will be better..

Comment: @Tj3n yes, I tried that. It doesn't understand that there's two `.a` files, so I'd have to leave out arm64 simulator support, which I'm not keen on. Mostly though, `.vendored_library` doesn't do anything about the swiftmodule. It's all centered around objective-C header files and nothing else :-(